# Como destruir uma session em java?

Tags: java-ee, session, login, java

Para invalidar uma sessão, meu professor passou o seguinte código:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);  
    if (session!=null){
        session.invalidate();
    }
```

Mas depois do logout, quando eu clico em Voltar no browser, consigo recuperar a mesma em que havia logado. Como consigo eliminá-la? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: O método para invalidar a sessão é este mesmo. Vc que criou a parte de segurança ou está utilizando algum framework?

Comment: Olá oveRider.  O método invalidate faz o que você está querendo. Veja se seu navegador não está cacheando a página anterior, gerlamente isso é resolvido adicionando alguns headers à resposta.

Comment: O método está correto, somente isso deveria ser o suficente para desconectar o usuário, caso vc não esteja usando algum recurso de "Lembrar-me". Acho que o problema não está ai.

Comment: Você atualizou a página após voltar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar isso:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
    {
        cookies[i].setMaxAge(-1); // se -1 nao funcionar tente 0 nao lembro bem essa parte
        resp.addCookie(cookies[i]);
    }
}
```

se você ler a [documentação](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) fala que :

```
 "The server can maintain a session in many ways such as using cookies or rewriting URLs."
```

usando essas linhas (ou crie um method) você estará desligando os cookies.

PS: esse código não foi testado.